# Expanding entities and using interdependent entity extensions in breeze

Tags: javascript, entity-framework, breeze

I'm trying to develop the most efficient way to work with entity expansion in queries and entity extensions that reference related entities.  I've come up against a problem where the order in which intializers are applied seems to be critical.

I've got a couple of initializers that extend breeze entities.  Basically, these sum values from child entities to display as totals in the parent entity.  My entity hierarchy is project>invoices>fees.  In my modelBuilder.js, I first extend the invoice entity to total fees, and then extend the project entity to total invoices.

This is all good when I query Invoices alone, or query projects and expand with invoices and fees.  However, when I query Invoices and expand with the project (to get name, client etc.), even if I expand with fees, breeze calls the project initializer before the invoice initializer, meaning I don't get to extend the project entity with invoiceTotal.  I have put a condition in to stop the code failing, but I'd like to know if there is a way to control the order in which the initializers occur in such a scenario.  I'm concerned that creating a dependency on expanding the invoice entity with fees for the invoiceInitializer to work isn't best practice.

This is the code in modelBuilder:

```
function extendMetadata(metadataStore) {

        metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor(
            'Person', function () { this.isPartial = false; }, personInitializer);
        metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor(
            'Invoice', function () { this.isPartial = false; }, invoiceInitializer);
        metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor(
            'Project', function () { this.isPartial = false; }, projectInitializer);
    }

    function personInitializer(person) {
        person.fullName = ko.computed(function () {
            return person.firstName() + ' ' + person.lastName();
        });
        return person;

    }

    function invoiceInitializer(invoice) {

        invoice.feeTotal = ko.computed(function () {
            var s = 0;
            $.each(invoice.fees(), function (i, el) { s += el.amount(); });
            return s;
        });

        return invoice;

    }

    function projectInitializer(project) {

        if (project.invoices().feeTotal) {
            project.invoiceTotal = ko.computed(function () {
                var s = 0.00;
                $.each(project.invoices(), function (i, el) { s += el.feeTotal(); });
                return s;
            });
        }
        if (project.projectPeople())
        {

        project.intPeopleString = ko.computed(function () {
            var s = '';
            $.each(project.projectPeople(), function (i, el) {
                if(el.isInternal())
                    s += el.person().firstName() + ' ' + el.person().lastName() + ', ';
            });
            if (s.length > 0)
            { s = s.substring(0, s.length - 2); }
            //alert(s);
            return s;
        });
        project.extPeopleString = ko.computed(function () {
            var s = '';
            $.each(project.projectPeople(), function (i, el) {
                if (!el.isInternal())
                    s += el.person().fullName() + ', ';
            });
            if (s.length > 0)
            { s = s.substring(0, s.length - 2); }
            return s;
        });
        }


        return project;

    }
```

And this is the calling code:

```
return uow.invoices.allExpanded('fees, invoiceStatus, project, project.client').then(function (data) {
                self.invoices(data);
            });
```

Which in turn calls:

```
this.allExpanded = function (exp) {
            var query = breeze.EntityQuery
                .from(resourceName)
            .expand(exp);
            return executeQuery(query);
        };
function executeQuery(query) {
            return entityManagerProvider.manager()
                .executeQuery(query.using(fetchStrategy || breeze.FetchStrategy.FromServer))
                .then(function(data) { return data.results; });
        }
```

This might also be a more general issue of whether I'm making the most efficient use of the expand functionality - i.e. I have lots of queries that expand entities but only really need one or two properties from the related entity.  For example, project usually expands with client, but generally only clientName and clientLocation are needed, but I don't want to use a DTO/projection because I'm using the viewmodel for CRUD activity).